# Возможно ли активировать виртуальное окружение в консоли через файл с командами?

Tags: bash, консоль, shell, virtualenv

Я каждый день запускаю свой django проект и использую следующие команды:

```
cd myProject
source venv/bin/activate
cd djangoproject
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Захотел немного сократить количество действий создал файл start.txt содержащий эти команды.

при запуске `bash start.txt` все корректно сработало, но виртуальное окружение не активировалось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Виртуальное окружение задаёт переменные окружения для *текущего* bash процесса.

Соответственно, запуская новый bash вы запускаете окружение в нём, родительский процесс не меняется после завершения скрипта.

Попробуйте не запускать start-скрипт, а сделать `source start.txt`